# Adding an if statement to the for loop code to hide the covers

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

What I want to do is hide the covers after they are clicked using an if statement placed in the for loop code. If that’s where it would go.

Preventing this from occurring.

[image]

I attempted to do that here but wasn't able to figure it out.

What am I doing wrong in trying to figure this out?

https://jsfiddle.net/8mg0v6eL/2/

```
(function manageCover() {
    "use strict";

    function hide(el) {
        el.classList.add("hide");
    }

    /*function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const cover = evt.currentTarget;
        hide(cover);
    }*/

    function addCoverListener(evt) {
        const cover = evt.target;

        const coversSelector = ".jacket-left, .jacket-middle, .jacket-right";
        const covers = document.querySelectorAll(coversSelector);

        for (let i = 0; i < covers.length; i += 1) {
            /*covers[i].addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);*/
            if (covers[i] !== evt.target) covers[i].hide(cover);
        }
    }

}());
```

Comment: You could directly select the currently hidden covers with `[class~="hide"]` and the visible one with `:not([class~="hide"]`. And you could use `classList.toggle()` instead of `classList.add()` if you want to be able to use the same function to remove `.hide` as well.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this please? Could you provide an example on here? This is something that someone told me to do. How would it be written into the code?

Comment: What exactly do you want? At the start we have 3 closed covers. I click the first cover, it expands and shows the video. Should this cover close again once I click a different one? Or should this cover close only when I click this same cover? In other words, should there only be one cover open at the same time?

Comment: No, the videos would stay open, the covers would just remain hidden, that's all.

Comment: I still don't get it. We start with 3 closed covers. When should they open and when should they close? Should they never open at all?

Comment: After the covers/pictures are clicked, they should disappear after. The videos would stay open, the pictures would then be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manageCover code does not really add much.
You only have to add one line of code to `coverClickHandler()`:

```
function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
    show(wrapper);
    initPlayer(wrapper);
    // Hide the clicked cover so only the video below is visible.
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add( 'hide' );
}
```

`evt.currentTarget` refers to the cover we clicked, so we can just add the `.hide` class to it to set it's display to none. If you do have to use manageCover in some way, either call `manageCover.hide( evt.currentTarget )` inside `coverClickHandler`, or add another click handler to the cover.

https://jsfiddle.net/yr2en3Lp/

```js
const load = (function makeLoad() {
    "use strict";

    function _load(tag) {
        return function (url) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                const element = document.createElement(tag);
                const parent = "body";
                const attr = "src";
                element.onload = function () {
                    resolve(url);
                };
                element[attr] = url;
                document[parent].appendChild(element);
            });
        };
    }
    return {
        js: _load("script")
    };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
    "use strict";
    const players = [];

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        player.setVolume(100); // percent
    }

    let hasShuffled = false;

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        if (!hasShuffled) {
            player.setShuffle(true);
            player.playVideoAt(0);
            hasShuffled = true;
        }
        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                if (players[i] !== event.target) players[i].pauseVideo();
            }
        }

        const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
        if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
        }
    }

    function addVideo(video, settings) {
        players.push(new YT.Player(video, Object.assign({
            videoId: video.dataset.id,
            host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
            events: {
                "onReady": onPlayerReady,
                "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
            }
        }, settings)));
    }

    function init(video, settings) {
        load.js("https://www.youtube.com/player_api").then(function () {
            YT.ready(function () {
                addVideo(video, settings);
            });
        });
    }
    return {
        init
    };
}());

function loadPlayer(opts) {
    "use strict";

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function initPlayer(wrapper) {
        const video = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
        opts.width = opts.width || 198;
        opts.height = opts.height || 198;
        opts.autoplay = 1;
        opts.controls = 1;
        opts.rel = 0;
        opts.iv_load_policy = 3;
        opts.fs = 0;
        opts.disablekb = 1;

        function paramInOpts(settings, param) {
            if (opts[param] !== undefined) {
                settings[param] = opts[param];
            }
            return settings;
        }
        const settingsParams = ["width", "height", "videoid", "host"];
        const settings = settingsParams.reduce(paramInOpts, {});
        const playerVarsParams = ["autoplay", "cc_load_policy",
            "controls", "disablekb", "end", "fs", "iv_load_policy",
            "list", "listType", "loop", "playlist", "rel", "start"
        ];
        settings.playerVars = playerVarsParams.reduce(paramInOpts, {});
        videoPlayer.init(video, settings);
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      evt.currentTarget.classList.add( 'hide' );
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        initPlayer(wrapper);
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(opts.target);
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}
const playlist = "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g";

loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacket-left",
    width: 277,
    height: 207
});

loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacket-middle",
    width: 277,
    height: 207
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacket-right",
    width: 277,
    height: 207
});

// These players do not have a HTML element.
// Will throw an error when attaching the click event.
/*
loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacketc",
    width: 600,
    height: 338,
    loop: true,
    playlist
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".alpha",
    start: 0,
    end: 280,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".beta",
    start: 0,
    end: 240,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".gamma",
    start: 0,
    end: 265,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".delta",
    start: 4,
    end: 254,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".epsilon",
    start: 0,
    end: 242,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".zeta",
    start: 0,
    end: 285,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".eta",
    start: 23,
    end: 312,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".theta",
    start: 2
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".iota"
});
*/
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container {
  width: 936px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #0059dd;
  background: #000000;
}

.container-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/jEMIULl.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.v-contain {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 277px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.jacket {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/fzdYu8g.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}
.jacket.hide {
  display: hidden;
}

.jacket-middle {
  background-position: 0 -80px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.jacket-right {
  background-position: 0 -80px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease 0s;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 0 10px;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 38px;
  height: 22px;
  fill: #0059dd;
}

.circle:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.circle:hover .play {
  fill: red;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 277px;
  height: 207px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

/*
.container-left-video .wrap-left iframe, 
.container-middle-video .wrap-middle iframe, 
.container-right-video .wrap-right iframe {
*/
.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 277px;
  height: 207px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tcell">
    <div class="container ">
      <div class="container-top">
        <div class="v-contain">
          <div class="jacket jacket-left">
            <div class="circle"> <svg class="play" width="38" height="22" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M7.712 22.04a.732.732 0 0 1-.806.007.767.767 0 0 1-.406-.703V4.656c0-.31.135-.544.406-.703.271-.16.54-.157.806.006l14.458 8.332c.266.163.4.4.4.709 0 .31-.134.546-.4.71L7.712 22.04z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrap hide">
            <div class="video" data-id="jMAShwisnQI"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="v-contain">
          <div class="jacket jacket-middle">
            <div class="circle"> <svg class="play" width="38" height="22" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M7.712 22.04a.732.732 0 0 1-.806.007.767.767 0 0 1-.406-.703V4.656c0-.31.135-.544.406-.703.271-.16.54-.157.806.006l14.458 8.332c.266.163.4.4.4.709 0 .31-.134.546-.4.71L7.712 22.04z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrap hide">
            <div class="video" data-id="-SiGnAi845o"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="v-contain">
          <div class="jacket jacket-right">
            <div class="circle"> <svg class="play" width="38" height="22" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M7.712 22.04a.732.732 0 0 1-.806.007.767.767 0 0 1-.406-.703V4.656c0-.31.135-.544.406-.703.271-.16.54-.157.806.006l14.458 8.332c.266.163.4.4.4.709 0 .31-.134.546-.4.71L7.712 22.04z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrap hide">
            <div class="video" data-id="-SiGnAi845o"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed 2 mangeCovers from the code. There are 3 though. How would I get that to work on .jacketd? It's the bottom left one. https://jsfiddle.net/qpnv7gf9/3/

Comment: Would that technique be able to work on .jacketd?

or, would that one need to stay?

Comment: I don't understand again. `.jacketd` has a different  HTML structure and does not contain a video, so it'll need different code, since `evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling` will not refer to the correct element. Which part is the cover in the case of jacketd and should be hidden?

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to know. Also, thank you for your help.

Comment: So if the question is: can I remove all the `.jacketd` stuff, yes. :)

Comment: Really? How would that be done? Could you provide a working jsfiddle with that implemented in it please?

Comment: I don't understand how that would be done. Removing all that stuff from .jacketd. What would be used in its place?

Comment: I just cut out all the HTML that wasn't jacket-left, jacket-middle or jacket-right, since the other ones did not have the click event.

Comment: How would you do that with jacketd?

Comment: Isn't everything in there needed for jacketd? https://jsfiddle.net/pyc83qvb/ The code breaks if you remove something from it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just don't understand. jacketd does not have a click event. And it does not have a hidden video beneath it to show since it's just an svg arrow drawn. The nextSibling is another element already. SO I have no clue what exactly you want to do with jacketd.

Comment: .jacketd needs to stay as it is then.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it by adding the following code inside your `manageCover()` IIFE, without making any changes to the available code. You can try it out!

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {

    switch (true) {
      case e.target.classList.contains("play"):
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("hide");
        break;
      case e.target.tagName === "path":
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle(
          "hide"
        );
        break;
      case e.target.classList.contains("circle"):
        e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle("hide");
        break;
    }
  });
```